# dd fails to restore partition

Tags: hard-drive, backup, dd

Being my own sysadmin for 24 years have never had to do a dd partition level restore of a backup - now my first attempt to so fails.  Everything I've read implies this should be straight-forward, but am not finding it so.

Needing to upgrade my kubuntu-14.04 (32-bit) I added 2 different 64-bit distros 2 weeks ago to check them out.  To do so I used gparted to shrink the 3 partitions of my original OS ( /home, /opt, / ) to make space above them - all went well and all 3 distros were working for 2 weeks.

Still using my original OS, yesterday I decided, for some misbegotten reason, to slightly increase the size of my /opt (sda6) by similarly decreasing my /home (sda5) using gparted.  Just to be safe, I did a dd backup of all 3 partitions and a sfdisk backup of my extended partitions (also a dd backup of my MBR, but that should not be changing).  But after the resizing, booting to the OS failed after the os login screen.

Since had only changed sda5 and sda6 (/home and /opt), I first used sfdisk to restore the extended partitions, then dd to restore those partitions.  But again booting failed after the login screen.  So decided to also restore the dd backup of / (sda7) even though that should not have changed. (All dd commands used bs=512 and the dd file sizes matched the allocated partition table sector sizes)
But got same failure.  Examining syslog, I see a "kernel ...Xsession ... segfault  ... in bash ..." at its end.

Again running gparted, it reports "input/output error on /dev/sda7"  (/)

Having nothing to lose, I tried to restore the superblock, using mke2fs to find locations of backups - that gave 10 values.  But using the first in e2fsck gave 'Output error while trying to open /dev/sda7'.

So decided to see what wisdom I could find here, since my sysadmin background is thin - something I do only as needed and so very sporadic.  FWIW, I do have a tarball of / directory made before adding distros and am thinking of untarring it to an emptied sda7, since I've not made any significant changes to / since then.  Perhaps somehow restoring superblock is an alternative.  But want to see if someone here has better ideas!

Comment: You actually have provided little debugging information.  All you mention is "*booting failed*" after your various steps, but the exact messages and *how* & *what* failed would determine the corrective actions needed.  Since you only provide summations of what you did, we are forced to assume that these operations were performed correctly, but since the outcomes were failures, such assumptions are probably invalid.

Comment: Testing to restore a backup is as important as making the backup.

Comment: Sounds a bit like your hard drive just happens to be dying.

Comment: Have you tried using testdisk?   It has significant abilities to fix partitioning issues.

Comment: Resolution: fixed partition problems but then stopped by blank screen after login, with syslog reporting same segfault described above. Replacing home partition with tarball backup gave working os! However after making changes in home directory, attempt to backup altered home partition with tar using rescuedisk failed mid-run with I/O fault messages.  On power off, power up BIOS did not recognize sda drive.  So drive was indeed failing - and quickly.  Thankfully I now know current backups can be used to re-create os.